# How to Redirect WordPress domain.com/?anyword to 404 Page?

Tags: redirect, 404-error, slug, homepage, home-url

Recently I Found some error on WordPress sites that when someone enter a question mark after the root domain and type any word, url shows the Home Page of instance:

For instance, Root Domain is abc.com abc.com/?anyword should be reached on the 404 not found page which shows the home page.

I need help with this Issue:
https://www.iadm.edu.pk/?anyword should be redirected to the 404 not found page.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in most cases, a logical thing to show the homepage even when there are querystrings available. Never the less, I'm assuming you have a reason for this. You could try code below to redirect your visitors to your 404 page:

```
if ( isset($_GET) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 );
    exit();
}
```

Keep in mind that some other functionality might break because of this. You may want to add some additional conditionals.

Comment: Where can I set this code, can you specify it, in the function.php or template page?

The reason I ask is that so many such links have been indexed in Google.

I will be able to remove it from Google's indexing. But I don't want to re-index such links.

Another problem that I am facing is with http http://www.iadm.edu.pk/?anyword, which will redirect to HTTPS and show the home page http links are also indexed in Google whereas i set my domain with https https://www. format.